# Wrap python callable in keras layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, tensorflow2.0

In keras / tensorflow it is often quite simple to describe layers directly as functions that map their input to an output, like so:

```py
def resnet_block(x, kernel_size):
   ch = x.shape[-1]
   out = Conv2D(ch, kernel_size, strides = (1,1), padding='same', activation='relu')(x)
   out = Conv2D(ch, kernel_size, strides = (1,1), padding='same', activation='relu')(out)
   out = Add()([x,out])
   return out
```

whereas subclassing `Layer` to get something like

```py
r = ResNetBlock(kernel_size=(3,3))
y = r(x)
```

is a little more cumbersome (or even a lot more cumbersome for more complex examples).

Since keras seems perfectly happy to construct the underlying weights of its layers when they're being called for the first time, I was wondering if it was possible to just wrap functions such as the one above and let keras figure things out once there are inputs, i.e. I would like it to look like this:

```py
r = FunctionWrapperLayer(lambda x:resnet_block(x, kernel_size=(3,3)))
y = r(x)
```

I've made an attempt at implementing `FunctionWrapperLayer`, which looks as follows:

```py
class FunctionWrapperLayer(Layer):
    def __init__(self, fn):
        super(FunctionWrapperLayer, self).__init__()
        self.fn = fn
    
    def build(self, input_shape):
        shape = input_shape[1:]
        inputs = Input(shape)
        outputs = self.fn(inputs)
        self.model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)
        self.model.compile()
        
    def call(self, x):
        return self.model(x)
```

This looks like it might work, however I've run into some bizarre issues whenever I use activations, e.g. with

```py
def bad(x):
    out = tf.keras.activations.sigmoid(x)
    out = Conv2D(1, (1,1), strides=(1,1), padding='same')(out)
    return out
x = tf.constant(tf.reshape(tf.range(48,dtype=tf.float32),[1,4,-1,1])
w = FunctionWrapperLayer(bad)
w(x)
```

I get the following error

```
FailedPreconditionError:  Error while reading resource variable _AnonymousVar34 from Container: localhost. This could mean that the variable was uninitialized. Not found: Resource localhost/_AnonymousVar34/class tensorflow::Var does not exist.
     [[node conv2d_6/BiasAdd/ReadVariableOp (defined at <ipython-input-33-fc380d9255c5>:12) ]] [Op:__inference_keras_scratch_graph_353]
```

What this suggests to me is that there is something inherently wrong with initializing models like that in the build method. Maybe someone has a better idea as to what might be going on there or how else to get the functionality I would like.

Update:
As mentioned by jr15, the above does work when the function involved only uses keras layers. However, the following ALSO works, which has me a little puzzled:

```py
i = Input(x.shape[1:])
o = bad(i)
model = Model(inputs=i, outputs=o)
model(x)
```

Incidentally, `model.submodules` yields

```
(<tensorflow.python.keras.engine.input_layer.InputLayer at 0x219d80c77c0>,
 <tensorflow.python.keras.engine.base_layer.TensorFlowOpLayer at 0x219d7afc820>,
 <tensorflow.python.keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D at 0x219d7deafa0>)
```

meaning the activation is automatically turned into a "TensorFlowOpLayer" when doing it like that.

Another update:
Looking at the original error message, it seems like the activation isn't the only culprit. If I remove the convolution and use the wrapper everything works as well and again I find a "TensorFlowOpLayer" when inspecting the submodules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Tensorflow 2.4 it apparently just works now. The submodules now show a "TFOpLambda" layer.

To anybody interested, here is some slightly improved wrapper code that also accommodates multi-input models:

```
class FunctionWrapperLayer(Layer):
    def __init__(self, fn):
        super(FunctionWrapperLayer, self).__init__()
        self.fn = fn
        
    def build(self, input_shapes):
        super(FunctionWrapperLayer, self).build(input_shapes)
        if type(input_shapes) is list:
            inputs = [Input(shape[1:]) for shape in input_shapes]
        else:
            inputs = Input(input_shapes[1:])
        outputs = self.fn(inputs)
        self.fn_model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)
        self.fn_model.compile()
        
    def call(self, x):
        return self.fn_model(x)
```

Answer (score 1):

You solution actually works! The trouble you're running into is that `tf.keras.activations.sigmoid` is not a Layer, but a plain Tensorflow function. To make it work, use `keras.layers.Activation("sigmoid")(x)` instead. For the more general case, where you want to use some Tensorflow function as a layer, you can wrap it in a Lambda layer like so:

```
out = keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: tf.some_function(x))(out)
```

See the docs for more info: https://keras.io/api/layers/core_layers/lambda/

Comment: You might well be right, but when building a model outside of the build method I never encounter the same bug. I.e. when I do 
`i = Input(x.shape[1:])`
`o = bad(i)`
`model = Model(inputs=i, outputs=o)`
`model(x)`
it appears to work. In terms of the API is that also not allowed and I'm just getting away with it because of some implementation detail?

Comment: I should add that I did try with layers instead of plain functions and that worked as far as I could tell.

Comment: @Cereal Interesting. I think what is going on is that when you create a layer or model within another layer and add it as an attribute, the outer layer automatically tracks the weights of the inner object (see https://keras.io/guides/making_new_layers_and_models_via_subclassing/#layers-are-recursively-composable). So I am guessing it only complains about that sigmoid when it's inside your custom layer because it's trying to track the weights, but it's not able to check if there are weights to track (even though we know it doesn't have any weights) because the sigmoid is not a proper layer.

Comment: Looking at the first error message, it doesn't seem like the activation is really at fault either. I've since tried it without the subsequent convolution and that does work! Really strange. My original post has been amended to reflect these findings. I don't know if you have any other ideas. If I don't find anything conclusive I will probably shy away from actually using my wrapper (although I'd certainly like to know at least why what I'm doing is not allowed).

Comment: @Cereal I have discovered even more peculiarities. Putting the convolution before the activation in `bad` works just fine! It seems that this is the recipe for failure: Having any non-`Layer` operation any time before a stateful `Layer` in the callable (stateless layers like `Flatten` and `MaxPooling2D` are ok, it seems). I'm not sure exactly what to make of this. Given that you can wrap non-layer ops in a `Lambda` layer, or just call `bad` directly and avoid the wrapper altogether, it seems that you can work around it. But I am curious why we are seeing this behavior

Comment: It looks like something about this particular way of nesting a model within a layer keeps the variables of stateful layers from being initialized when they need to be. You're right, I can certainly work around it (though the whole point was to get something I can plug into `Sequential` and subclass so it'll look pretty when using `tf.keras.utils.plot_model` and the like).

Comment: I don't know if you care, but Tensorflow 2.4 appears to have fixed it. It just works now